# How to Change HTML Tags Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags, edit

I have some HTML code that looks like this:

```
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
```

And I would like to change it to this:

```
<textarea maxlength="300" name="message"></textarea>
```

How can I accomplish this using Javascript? I have tried a lot of different code from a lot of different places, but none of them seem to work. If need be, I will accept CSS code too.

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: This question could be rephrased as "how many identical uses of `setAttribute` can there be?"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
$('textarea').attr('maxlength', 300);
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it if you aren't using jQuery (highly recommended):

```
var myelement = document.getElementsByName('message')[0];
myelement.setAttribute('maxlength',300);
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq779/)

Comment: An exact copy of @Rami Enbashi's answer, posted 10 minutes later.

Comment: My apologies, I wrote it myself, and didn't see that at the time of writing. That's just the best way to do it.

Comment: I don't actually mind, I'm in a snippy mood right now. Hence my above comment, "This question could be rephrased as 'how many identical uses of setAttribute can there be?'"

Comment: Yeah I saw that at some point, thought it was funny. I try to answer questions even if there is another solution, aka use jQuery, in case it helps, and sometimes dev is frustrating. It can help if someone just gives you the answer without extra BS sometimes, so that's what I aim to do.

Answer (score 0):

Match the tag element using jquery and then use the .attr() function.

Comment: jQuery is not always the answer.

Comment: "I don't always use jQuery, but when I do, I prefer dos point oh. Stay scripty my friends." - Most Interesting Developer in the World

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using jQuery:

```
<textarea id="text" name="message"></textarea>
```

```
var element = document.getElementById("text");
element.setAttribute("maxlength","300");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/35JvV/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('[name="message"]').setAttribute('maxlength', 300)
```